# Changing WinForms TextBox to BorderStyle.None causes text to be cut off

Tags: winforms

i've changed a WinForms `TextBox` control to have no border.

When i do the bottom pixel row of text in the box is being cut off.

**Top:** `BorderStyle.Fixed3D` (default).  **Bottom:** `BorderStyle.None`

[image]

You can see the last bit of text in the un-bordered text box is cut off:

[image]

How do i convince a `TextBox` (who's height cannot be changed), that it needs to be taller?

Comment: isn't there a autosize property that you could either turn on or off for that.? you should be able to set the width and height as well unless I am deeply mistaken.

Comment: You are, in fact, deeply mistaken. You are thinking of `AutoSize` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize.aspx). My first thought was that too; toggle it off and on so that .NET gets its head out of its assembly. But `TextBox` has no `AutoSize` property. Also any attempts to adjust the height of a TextBox (e.g. `Height`, `Bounds.Height`, `ClientRectangle`, `ClientSize`) ignore any height changes. The `TextBox` decides it's height for itself and that's that.

Comment: Try a loo here [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46564085/3998265) it is pretty similar

Answer (score 2):

The `AutoSize` property is there, just inherit from `TextBox` and you can get to the property:

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox {

  public TextBoxEx() {
    base.AutoSize = false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Multiline = true;
    textBox1.MinimumSize = new Size(0, 30);
    textBox1.Size = new Size(textBox1.Size.Width, 30);
    textBox1.Multiline = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your form:

```
    private void RefreshHeight(TextBox textbox)
    {
        textbox.Multiline = true;
        Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textbox.Text, textbox.Font, Size.Empty, TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
        textbox.MinimumSize = new Size(0, s.Height + 1);
        textbox.Multiline = false;
    }
```

Then you say `RefreshHeight(textbox1);`

`Multiline` change will force the textbox to "accept" the new size

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix this in the Visual Studio Designer.

Change the height in the minimum size property for the text box.  Change to multiline=true, then back to false.  The text box will resize and stay fix.

No code changes needed.

Comment: This doesn't work in VS 2017. It switches right back. Missing a step?

Comment: VS2013.  Maybe 2017 does it different.

Comment: Works in VS 2008