# "TextBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None" makes bottom of text invisible

Tags: c#, winforms

Whenever I set a TextBox's border style to "None" the bottom of text in the box is invisible. That means I can't see underscores and descenders of letters like y and j.

[Here is the textbox with border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2JKs.png)

[Here is the textbox without border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDjnP.png)

Any suggestions as to how this is solved would be appreciated.

Comment: Increase the height of your textbox.

Comment: A little bit of research effort would have given you this link [BorderStyle.None causes text to be cutoff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481333/changing-winforms-textbox-to-borderstyle-none-causes-text-to-be-cut-off) which is exactly the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed to work for me:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Multiline = true;
    textBox1.MinimumSize = new Size(0, 30);
    textBox1.Size = new Size(textBox1.Size.Width, 30);
    textBox1.Multiline = false;
}
```

Setting box to multi line to adjust size of the box then when its changed back keeps the size.